# Second input take " " without me choosing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is just this :

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
print('The sum of ', x, ' and ', y, ' is ', x+y, '.', sep='')
```

I get this error when i enter any number :

```
Enter a number:15

Enter a second number: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/mgt4/PycharmProjects/Beamy/test.py", line 5, in <module>
  y = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I understand that it thinks the second number entered is a space but I don't know why and how i can fix this.

Comment: cannot reproduce. did you try to run your code from the terminal?

Comment: if you type "return" twice, you probably get that effect

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want your program to attempt to continue even if the user chooses to enter a space for the second input prompt?

Comment: FYI: If you leave `sep=''` away you don't need to manually insert spaces into the `print` arguments. (I guess you did it intentionally to avoid the space before the `.`, better use `str.format` then)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Strange when i run from my terminal it work but not with PyCharm. Any idea why ?

Comment: @ChristianDean I only type one of the number and it end my program, it seems it's an issu with PyCharm since it work when I do it with my terminal

Comment: Hmm, that is strange @MathieuGalant. Are you _sure_ you're not pressing enter twice?

Comment: @ChristianDean Yeah i just retry to make sure i wasn't pressing it twice still the same

Comment: @MathieuGalant  PyCharm seems to be doing quite a few unexpected things when executing your code - there recently was a question about a Django ORM query being actually executed when the script itself did not evaluate it at all, just constructed it.

Answer (score 1):

`int(input("whatever"))` will indeed raise a `ValueError` if `input()` returns something that can not be interpreted as an int. As a general rule, you should never trust user inputs (wherever they come from - `input()`, command line arguments, `sys.stdin`, text files, HTTP request, whatever) and always sanitize and validate them.

For your use case, you want a wrapper function around the `int(input(...))` call:

```
def asknum(q):
    while True:
        raw = input(q)
        try:
            return int(raw.strip())
        except ValueError:
            print("'{}' is not a valid integer".format(raw)


num1 = asknum("enter an integer")
```

You could make it a bit more generic by providing a validation function instead:

```
def ask(q, validate):
    while True:
        raw = input(q)
        try:
            return validate(raw.strip())
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
```

And in this case you can simply use the `int` type as validation function:

```
num1 = ask("enter an integer", int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to transform your code more generic:

```
REPEATS = 2 
  counter = 1 
  values = []
  while True:
      value = raw_input("Enter number {}: ".format(counter))
      try:
          number = int(value)
      except ValueError:
          print("Entered value '{}' isn't a number".format(value))
          continue
      counter += 1
      values.append(number)
      if counter > REPEATS:
          break

  print('The sum of values {} is {}'.format(", ".join([str(v) for v in values]), sum(values)))
```

Where `REPEATS` will be number of added values.

```
Example of output:
Enter number 1: 56
Enter number 2: 88
The sum of values 56, 88 is 144
```